# How to update two tables in SQL based on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`.

- `Table1` contains `ID (UniqueIdentifier) PK, IsActive (bit), ExpiryDate (DateTime), LastUpdateDT (Datetime)`
- `Table2` contains `ID (uniqueIdentifier) PK, Table1ID (FK to Table1), IsActive (bit), LastUpdateDt (datetime)`

There are multiple rows in `Table2` pointing to same PK of `Table1`.

Now I have declared a variable `@Now = Getdate()`. I want to find all the ID's from Table1 for which `IsActive = 1` and `ExpiryDate < @Now`. Using these Id's I want to update `IsActive` flag as well as `LastUpdateDt` in both tables to 0 and `@Now` respectively.

how can I implement this logic in SQL?

At a time there can multiple rows from Table1 satisfying this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID UniqueIdentifier);

DECLARE @Now DATETIME = Getdate();

UPDATE Table1
 SET IsActive = 0,
     LastUpdateDt = @Now
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO #temp(ID)    
WHERE IsActive = 1 and ExpiryDate < @Now

UPDATE Table2
 SET IsActive = 0,
     LastUpdateDt = @Now   
WHERE IsActive = 1 and ExpiryDate < @Now
AND Table1ID IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM #temp)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: a quick question If I want to add multiple columns in temp table from Table1 and user them in Where clause for table2, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
SET @Now = GETDATE()
```

Update Table2 first

```
Update Table2
Set IsActive=0,
LastUpdateDT=@Now
WHERE Table1ID in (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE IsActive = 1 AND ExpiryDate < @Now)
```

Update Table1 now

```
Update Table1
Set IsActive=0,
LastUpdateDT=@Now
WHERE IsActive = 1 AND ExpiryDate < @Now
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.... and sorry for late reply.... But I wanted to update like hundreds of rows and I was looking for a more reliable way. Yours is a good and simple solution though.